# how to use parameters in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to print the list of title and dob in the xml file. But I can not find the error in the code.Here I am trying this to understand exactly how parameters work in xsl

here is the xml code

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="aa.xslt"?> 
<tutorial>
    <section>
    <title>Gene Splicing for Young People</title>
    <panel>
        <title>Introduction1</title>
        <dob>86</dob>
        <dof>86</dof>
    <!-- ... -->
    </panel>
    <panel>
    <title>Discovering the secrets of life and creation</title>
    <dob>85</dob>
    <!-- ... -->
    </panel>
    <panel>
    <title>"I created him for good, but he's turned out evil!"</title>
    <dob>84</dob>
    <!-- ... -->
    </panel>
    <panel>
    <title>When angry mobs storm your castle</title>
    <dob>88</dob>
    <!-- ... -->
    </panel>
    </section>
</tutorial>
```

Here is the xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:template match="tutorial/section/panel">


  <xsl:call-tempate name="boo">
      <xsl:with-param name="myname" select="title" />
      <xsl:with-param name="mydob" select="dob" />
  </xsl:call-template>

</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template name="boo">
  <xsl:param name="myname" select="'Not Available'" />
  <xsl:param name="mydob" select="'Not Available'" />
  <div>
  NAME: <xsl:value-of select="$myname" />
  <br />
  DOB: <xsl:value-of select="$mydob" />
  <hr />
  </div>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

expecting output is,
Introduction1
86

Discovering ....
85

and etc.

Comment: You've provided your expected output. What's the actual output?  How is it different from the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to output the title of panel, so try changing:

```
<xsl:template match="tutorial/section">
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="tutorial/section/panel">
```

**Edit**

If you're having issues with "Not Available" showing up, it's because you are passing the parameter an empty string when the element doesn't exist and it overwrites the default value.

You could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="tutorial/section/panel">
    <xsl:call-template name="boo">
        <xsl:with-param name="myname">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Not Available</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="mydob">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="dob">
                    <xsl:value-of select="dob"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>Not Available</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>               
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

or something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="tutorial/section/panel">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="title and dob">
            <xsl:call-template name="boo">
                <xsl:with-param name="myname" select="title" />
                <xsl:with-param name="mydob" select="dob" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="dob">
            <xsl:call-template name="boo">
                <xsl:with-param name="mydob" select="dob" />
            </xsl:call-template>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="title">
            <xsl:call-template name="boo">
                <xsl:with-param name="myname" select="title" />
            </xsl:call-template>                
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="boo"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I update the code and checked but problem is still there. thanks figuring out me an error in my code.

Comment: do I need to add something like `<xsl:template name="boo" match="panel">`?

Comment: What is the problem? Is it that you're not getting the "Not Available" when the element doesn't exist? Also, you have a misspelled `xsl:call-template`.

Comment: when I correct the `xsl:call-template` everthing started to work. thanks lot.